# How to use GitHub to commit barely or never changed files only once

Tags: php, git, zend-framework, github

Reason: it takes quite a while to check changed files in GitHub Windows desktop version when there is large number of files in a project.

For example, Zend library could have huge set of files but I am never going to change anything in it. However, I still want it to be committed. So is there a way I can only commit them once then GitHub never checks change again?

Any answers, GUI, command line-ish are appreciated.

=================================================

**Edited after solved**

Thanks to dylanPowers, problem now solved. But I want to explain more for those who hear git submodule for the first time, and detail steps on how I got it work.

Let's say your Zend library should be in your project's 'library/Zend' folder. Before doing this, Zend folder should not exist because you are going to download it as a submodule.

My commands:

```
> git submodule add https://github.com/opensolutions/zf1.git library/Zend
```

By running above command, your console will start downloading submodule from https://github.com/opensolutions/zf1.git into your local folder 'library/Zend'. Then you can commit your code using the following command:

> git commit -a -m "Added ZF1 submodule"

Time to push, and you will notice your Zend library is not being uploaded at all. Because it is a repository on GitHub, there is no need to upload again!

```
git push
```

OK, now go to your project's webpage, in library folder, you will see a link to ZF1 repository (https://github.com/opensolutions/zf1.git). Done!

Git submodule is like composer, but it couldn't solve dependencies for you. So composer is also a very valuable point, which is answered below by ceejayoz, thank you.

This article was very helpful to me: http://joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/

Comment: You should be using Composer to include Zend in a `.gitignore`d `vendor/` directory rather than checking the whole thing into your repository. http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a library, I'd recommend accessing it through a [git-submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). The Zend Framework for instance is [on Github](https://github.com/zendframework) already. If you wanted zf2, you could then add it to your repo with the following commands:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/zendframework/zf2.git path/to/library/dir
git commit -m "Added Zend Framework submodule"
```

This should make GitHub for Windows ignore that directory with the Zend Framework because it isn't directly part of your git repository anymore.
For any other libraries you may be using that aren't version controlled through git, you could initialize it into a git repo yourself, and push that to GitHub or any other easily accessible place for that matter, and do the same thing.

Comment: I am ticking this one because it uses git itself to solve the problem. Also I like ceejayoz's answer which was written under the question because composer is becoming widely used. In this case I'm using ZF1. It's important to note the correct library git path is: https://github.com/opensolutions/zf1.git, this is the path with Zend library only.